# Obtain Model and Route data from ASP MVC unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

Is it possible to obtain both the Model and Route data from a ReSharper 7.1.3 unit test? It seems I have to choose between one or the other using the methods below

**Route Data**

```
//Execute controller action
var redirect = _controlAgtTran.Create(agency) as RedirectToRouteResult;

//Check route values since Model is not accessible
Assert.IsNotNull(redirect);
Assert.AreEqual("AgentTransmission", redirect.RouteValues["controller"]);
Assert.AreEqual("Index", redirect.RouteValues["action"]);
Assert.AreEqual("Record saved with status of 'Waiting'", redirect.RouteValues["msg"]);
```

**Model Info**

```
//Execute controller action
var result = _controlAgtTran.Create(agency) as ViewResult;
var model = result.Model as AgentTransmission;

//Check model properties since RouteValues is not accesible
Assert.AreEqual(model.RecordStatus, "P");
```

Comment: You can't really retrieve two results at the same time, you can either get ViewResult or RedirectToActionResult from an action. RedirectToActionResult does not have a model. Or are you trying to test routes?

Comment: @MyP3uK - I'd like to do both. Test the model and the route without having to run two tests

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to have separate tests for the routes.